# real time analytics for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, analytics

I wan to integrate analytics in one of my project. I know Flurry analytics and Google analytics are good options, but both of these server are not tracking realtime data. It shows update after few hours on dashboard.

Is There any real time Analytics tool/library available which I can easily integrate with ios App?

Comment: Check out countly, http://count.ly . They also have an open source solution that you can run yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On google Analytics, there is a real time tab, where you can watch how many users are using your app, where they are from, which version of your app they are using,...

Answer (score -1):

I really like [Appsee for real-time app analytics](https://www.appsee.com/?cpnid=7010N000000hv6x) - and it’s super easy to integrate with an iOS app. Session recordings is one of the coolest features they offer, and it allows you to see exactly what was going on in the user journey (trends, crashes, bugs, ANR, etc.). You see everything in real time, which is great for understanding any issues in the app and quickly fixing / improving.